# How to Add and Push a local git project to a remote branch

Tags: gitlab, git-branch

I have a local folder (say L) with some files and folders. 
On this L, I did git init.

At remote I created a repository and a branch with a file each. Means, 
at remote I have Master (say M) and a branch (say B)

NOTE : BOTH LOCAL AND REMOTE ARE NOT CONNECTED YET.

With this, I want to push my local repository L to the branch B or remote, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First you can pull the remote repository to your local machines. Then you can move your local folder (L) to the new local repo.

Then you can go for git add and git commit and git push.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I am new to git ( used SVN extensively). I know both do some stuff, but totally different way.

Answer (score 0):

```
NOTE : BOTH LOCAL AND REMOTE ARE NOT CONNECTED YET.
```

Here itself lies your answer.

1. You need to clone the remote repository say R and switch to the B branch
2. Copy the files from local repository L and place them in the cloned repository R.
3. Commit the files and Push.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I am new to git ( used SVN extensively). I know both do some stuff, but totally different way.